# XNA - Tiles/Grid/Tilemap VB or C#

Tags: user-interface, xna, collision, tiles

Still a bit of a noobie when it comes to XNA kind of stuff. So there are a few things I need help on, which may be a hefty order...not sure since I'm not too familiar :P

1) Draw/Generate Tiles, and a way to switch between seeing the grid lines and not.

2) Collision detection ( I would imagine having classes for things like Passable, Impassable, and such to be efficient)

3) I'm very unsure how to add a GUI/Menus for things like Inventory. I've been learning the past few years, primarily Object Oriented Programming using Visual Basic, so I'm used to drag-and-drop or adding objects via code (not as much). Not sure how to get things like labels/buttons and the sort for menus.

4) A map editor kind of system, for making areas quickly. And switch from area to area in-game..how to handle that process.

I'm not asking for ALL of these at once, just whatever anyone feels they can help with is great. Or links to other posts that seem to handle one or many of the above rather well.

I've been using VB for the most part, but I'm managing with seeing examples in C# and converting over to VB. So language choice hasn't been a problem so far :)

THANKS!

Comment: do you want to use a third-party libraries or interested in how to implement it by yourself?

Comment: Implementing myself would probably be best. So I know how it works.

Comment: Can I ask what type of game you are planning on? I can probably help with point 2. If it is a game like Zelda collision detection is easy.

Comment: if you need pixelperfect collision is a lot harder. (But I could give you my functions for that if you like.)

Drawing lines and primitives in xna is pretty hard but I'd recommend you look at the https://roundline.codeplex.com/

Creating a GUI in XNA for making editors is a pain.... I should one day take the time to make a windows.forms like interface for XNA.

Comment: I would just make an adventure-type game. Very simple to start. A player sprite, and some different tile styles for grass/tress/water/..passable and impassible...transition from one area to another

Comment: I already have a working, very simple, game that allows you to move a sprite around with the arrow keys and collides with a dedicated 'impassable' object. On a pixel by pixel basis, smooth movement to the eye as well.    The downside, I thought, to the pixel by pixel, was making maps/areas. Having something that allowed me to draw objects on a tile by tile basis (even in code), while maintaining my pixel by pixel abilities would be cool too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm studing how to make games by making [this monster](https://bitbucket.org/prostokiriuha/windrock/src/47376eb980c7?at=master). You can find my realization of GUI in [Graphics2D/GUI folder](https://bitbucket.org/prostokiriuha/windrock/src/47376eb980c7/GameHelper/Graphics2D/GUI/?at=master). Like a WinForms :D

P.S. Solution is not compilable in that moment.